# How can I see what happens in the terminal without using xterm?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xterm

So I want to run a simple script in a terminal windows such that the terminal window opens, my command(s) are being executed, and then it closes with an echo line. Like

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r /home/test
echo "test has been removed"
read
```

But the only way I can do it is by using xterm like

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e rm -r /home/test \
echo "test has been removed" \
read \
```

However, with the first solution I don't see any terminal windows, and with the second solution I have to write the stupid backslashes, and that makes the machine think that it's all one line I think, and in the second case there is no echo line... So my question is: How do I use xterm properly (I've tried putting everything after -e in quotes already).

Also, can it be that I have to use another way of scripting? Some commands are not accepted in the bash scripts if I understood correctly...

Alternatively, I would be happy if I could make the script executable and then click "trust this executable" . This would prevent the popup which asks me if I want to execute it in a terminal window or just execute it. But how do I trust it so it will run in a terminal window??

Comment: 1. You can run the first script in *any* terminal window, for example the default `gnome-terminal` of Ubuntu, not only in `xterm`; 2.In any terminal window you can run the script (in the same directory where you store it) with the command `./script` (the file name of the script), if you made it executable. -- You can find many good tutorials via the internet. Search for 'bash tutorial' (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! But I don't want to open a terminal myself. I want to create a script file that does everything: open the terminal, run the commands etc., so that I can start the computer and have all the script files I want to open upon startup (I know how to choose a file for startup)... Thanks again for any update ;)

Comment: 1. See my updated first comment; 2. There are different ways to run things at startup - either system commands in the background or commands in the graphical desktop environment. It seems you want the latter, and then you should create a desktop file, that runs a shellscript (and you put the desktop file in 'autostart'. So search the internet for 'linux desktop file' or some similar words ...

Comment: I did run that script according to your answer 1., but it just deletes the folder. I don't see any terminal window popping up, no echo message. Can you help again please?

Comment: Did you create a script? And start it in a terminal window? It should remove the file, echo the message and wait for input at `read` (wait until you have read the message and when you press the Enter key it will finish), and the terminal window will return to prompt. - If you want to do it via a desktop file, there are some examples at [this link](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en). Put the full path to the script file on the 'Exec' line.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear enough.. I want it all in a script file that I can click (or autostart) and that will do the following: 1. open a terminal. 2. type my command (remove the folder) 3. say that it is deleted 4. stay open (the read command is just a crutch, I just want to prevent the terminal from closing. I already have a script written and in autostart, and it does what it should, except for showing a terminal window. And I don't want to have to sit there to open a terminal and type anything, just one click (or autostart). I'm on lubuntu 19.10 with qterminal as default terminal

Comment: I perform this kind of task not with a single script, but with a desktop file, that calls a script file. If the task is simple, I might make a long command on the exec line (with commands separated by semicolons). Maybe you can get along with that. In Lubuntu 18.04  it is different from the other flavours of Ubuntu: You may be able to skip the desktop file, and simply add a command line with the terminal program and parameters into `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` - Is this what you use also in 19.10?

Comment: Here is an example of a command line with `xterm` that performs 3 commands separated by semicolons: `xterm -e bash -c 'echo hello; echo world; read'`

Comment: So there is no way to call the terminal, and then tell the terminal what it should "type", and have all that in one clickable file? I would like to post the whole code, but I have only 415 characters left. The only way I know to have a terminal window open by starting a script is to use #!/bin/bash \ xterm -e prysm.bat beacon-chain \ (where prysm.bat beacon-chain is the line that I would normally type in myself, the target purpose if you will. Without xterm -e there's no terminal, and it would perhaps run in the background, but there is a lot of text that's coming in that I want to see.

Comment: I think one way to do this is to 1. Create and test a shellscript file; 2. When you know that it works as you wish, you can start thinking about how to start it (automatically or manually); 3. Make it start the way you want. -- It is late here and I will go to bed now. If you want help from me tomorrow, you can put @sudodus into a comment, and I willl get an alert about it.

Comment: thank you, good night!

Comment: Yes, the `\` characters allow us to split commands into multiple lines. This is great for commenting hard parts so whomever comes later, including ourselves, can understand it more easily. Have you tried any redirecting of some/all output of the xterm call to stdout (`2>&1`) or stderr (`1>&2`)? May also need to pipe the echo output like `>1` or `>2` to get the echo to show up in the terminal. Could also try just `echo >&1` or `>&2`, followed by the text to print.